# Python New Env created by Anaconda Prompt not showing in Jupyter Notebook kernel list

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, kernel, tensorflow2.0, anaconda3

I created a new python env using Anaconda Prompt by using the following steps:

conda create --name py3-TF2.0 python=3

conda activate py3-TF2.0

conda install tensorflow

pip install --upgrade tensorflow

pip install ipykernel

then i restarted anaconda and opened jupyter notebook.
The problem is when i open a new notebook and go to kernel to choose the new env i could not find the env i created (p3-TF2.0)

however, when I use conda info --envs, i find the new env created.

what is missing here?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After activating the environment, try running:

```sh
python -m ipykernel install --user --name py3-TF2.0 --display-name "py3-TF2.0"
```

If this still isn't pointing to the correct environment (i.e. you can't import packages you know you installed in that environment), remove the `py3-TF2.0` kernel that's broken with `jupyter kernelspec remove py3-TF2.0`.

Then run `<your_path_to>/anaconda3/envs/py3-TF2.0/bin/python -m ipykernel install --user --name py3-TF2.0 --display-name "py3_TF2.0"`.

Additional help on [Jupyter Kernels](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install/kernel_install.html).

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue after running all the commands on anaconda prompt it still wasnt showing py2-TF2.0.

**[Note: Update your Anaconda Navigator]**

**steps 1 :**

conda create --name py3-TF2.0 python=3

conda activate py3-TF2.0

conda install tensorflow

pip install --upgrade tensorflow

pip install ipykernel

**step 2:**

**python -m ipykernel install --user --name=py3-TF2.0 --display-name "Python 3 (py3-TF2.0)"**

[Image of the Anaconda prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rdL4V.png)

**I changed Base(root) to py2-TF2.0 on Anaconda Navigator , and it worked for me.**

[This link has Screenshoot for reference, Hope this Solution helps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pNHMo.png)